# Is there a way to get clicked item from a GridView as an UI element in WinUI?

Tags: c#, winui-3

### Description of the situation

I have a `GridView` in my main page containing items binded to a list / array of classes.

```
<GridView x:Name="ImageListBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind displayedImages}" ItemClick="ImageListBox_ItemClick">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:DisplayedImage">
           <Border>
               <Image x:Name="ImageBoxMain" Source="{x:Bind ImagePath }"/>
           </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Each item displays an image downloaded from links fetched from web json (The content inside it changes frequently).

By clicking one of the image in the grid, the app navigates to a new page displaying a larger version of the same image together with more details of the image.

### What I wish to achieve

So I wish to animate the image from the small version in the `GridView` to the larger version displayed in the new page by using `ConnectedAnimation`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/connected-animation#forward-navigation) on `ConnectedAnimation`, I need to specify the `SourceImage` in order to establish the animation connection.

### What have I tried

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/connected-animation#forward-navigation), I have the following code placed in the `GridView` item click handler:

```
ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView()
      .PrepareToAnimate("forwardAnimation", ImageBoxMain);
```

### The problem

The problem I have is that I do not have a `SourceImage`. My image is part of a `GridView` and I did not manage to find a way to specify the image as an `UIElement`, which is what the `ConnectedAnimation` API expects.

In the XAML code snippet above, we can see that the actual image element is named `ImageBoxMain`, however it is not accessible from the code behind as seen from the image below:

[image: an image showing an error message "The type or namespace name 'ImageBoxMain' could not be found".]

`The type or namespace name 'ImageBoxMain' could not be found`

### The question

So with that, how can I get clicked item from a `GridView` as an `UIElement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GridView's XAML, make sure the IsItemClickEnabled property is set to "True".

In your page, declare a member variable to store the clicked item :

```
private GridViewItem _clickedItem;
```

In your ImageListBox_ItemClick method store the clicked item and navigate :

```
private void ImageListBox_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    _clickedItem = (GridViewItem)ImageListBox.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem);
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2), null, new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
}
```

As GridViewItem inherits from UIElement, you can use it as the source for the ConnectedAnimation :

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_clickedItem != null)
        {
            ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("forwardAnimation", _clickedItem);
        }

        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }
```

In the following page, the destination element for the animation can be anything (in the code I used for testing, it was a Rectangle element).